# regex: match 'customer' in string 'styles/customer.1031.css'

Tags: regex, node.js

I'm trying to extract the customer string out of a filepath in nodejs. So far I have come up with this:

```
var fileName = 'styles/customer.1031.css';
fileName = fileName.substring(7);
fileName = fileName.substring(0, fileName.length - 4);
fileName = fileName.match('[a-z]*')[0];
console.log(fileName); // <-- yields 'customer'
```

I'm cutting the `styles/` from the beginning and the `.css` from the end. Then I'm only matching the lowercase characters. What would be a proper regex to match only the customer string so I don't need to cut the string before? F. ex. how would the regex look like to catch everything after `styles/` until the `.`?

Comment: Specify the programming language that you use. Use tags for that

Comment: Done. I'm using nodejs.

Comment: The raw regex would be `^styles/([^.]+)\..*$`

Comment: `var m = fileName.match(/^styles\/(.*?)\./);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex to use could look like `^styles/([^.]+)\..*$` where

- `^styles/` translates to "starts with 'styles/'
- Then your match (at least one character, matching until first '.')
- Then a literal '.'
- Then anything until the end of the string (this is optional, depending on your needs)

Comment: If its a regex literal / needs escaping else \ needs escaping

Answer (score 1):

> How would the regex look like to catch everything after styles/ until
>   the .?

This is how it will look like:

`styles\/(.*?)\.`

Run it on [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/uN8lI5/1)

The caught string can then be accessed via `\1`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use non capturing group regex as `(?:styles\/)(.*?)\.`

```js
var fileName = 'styles/customer.1031.css';
console.log(/(?:styles\/)(.*?)\./.exec(fileName)[1])
```